# How it works in python? ruby code

Tags: python, ruby

I don't understand what it code doing, please help.

How it will be working in python or in another simple language?

```
a = []
a << [1]

for i in 2..10001
    f = 0
    a.each{ |group|
        m = 1
        group.each { |c|
            m *= i % c
        }
        f += m
        if m > 0
            group << i
            break
        end
    }
    a << [i] if f == 0
end

p a
p a.size
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what question you would like answered?

Comment: @Linuxios i don't understand clearly that code.

Comment: @Linuxios
would be nice if someone show same program on another language, more simply

Comment: That is not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: @DanielRoseman 

sorry if I broke the rules of stackoverflow
can please you mention a few services that may help me

Comment: @DimaKabaruhin: if you want someone to translate the code for you, you can hire a programmer. I will gladly send you my terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally translated to python this is:

```
a = []
a.append([1])

for i in range(2,10001 + 1):
    f = 0
    for group in a:
        m = 1
        for c in group:
            m *= i % c
        f += m
        if m > 0:
            group.append(i)
            break
    if f == 0:
        a.append([i])

print a
print len(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
a = []
a.append(1)

for i in range(2, 10000):
    f = 0
    for group in a:
        m = 1
        for c in group:
            m *= i%c
        f += m
        if m>0:
            group.append(i)
            break
    if not f:
        a.append(i)

print(a)
print(len(a))
```

Comment: Presumably the down-vote was for the wrong upper limit of range?

Comment: @JaredGoguen dunno. It's been a while since i did any ruby, so i'm not surprised i misremembered something, but i am surprised that someone would choose a loop bound of 10001

Comment: Even so, the upper bound on range would then be 10001 as it isn't inclusive.

Comment: In ruby `a..b` is a to b inclusive and `a...b` is a to b exclusive.